# Attribution for Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, licensing

I need to attribute Bootstrap in a new project I am working on. I can not find anything online that explains the proper steps for attributing Bootstrap. What I have right now is:

Built with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

And this will go in the footer, or where I can fit it in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about software licensing. Licensing and legal questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow -- see discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap is released under MIT license, so the only attribution you legally have to comply with is keeping the license file in place.

If you just want to do the good thing and let people know that you are using boostrap the choice of how to do that is yours. Don't think there is any official or even commonly used attribution style.

Comment: Thanks! I figured that was the case but I wanted to make absolutely sure before I go ahead with it.